# using variable for imageNamed instead of hard-coded string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do i use a variable as an image name instead of hard coding the string?

right now I'm using this

[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.jpg"]

I would like to pass a NSString variable instead of "one.png"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry if this misses your question, but you just pass the variable name.

```
NSString *myImageFile = @"one.jpg";
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:myImageFile];
```